# iOS Non Affine Transform

Tags: xcode, ios6, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

Is it posible to do a non-affine transform in Core graphics?

I want a perspective transform and can't seem to find any mention of something like it in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-affine transforms are managed by Core Animation, not Core Graphics. See `CATransform3D` in the [Core Animation Function Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html).

In short, in order to apply perspective, you will generally need to move from `UIView` to `CALayer`.